# How to get x86_energy_perf_policy // linux-tools-* for Linux kernel 4.7.0-xyz

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I am using [pstate-frequency](https://github.com/pyamsoft/pstate-frequency) to set our server cpu's frequency. This tool needs the `x86_energy_perf_policy` which is provided by the `linux-tools-common` package.

Using the distributions standard kernel I could simply install `linux-tools-common_4.4.0-18.34_all` and I am done.

Unfortunately, I use Linux kernel 4.7.0-040700 from the official [Ubuntu Kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7/).

How can I get `linux-tools-4.7.0-040700-generic` on our server? Most likely I need to build it, where can I find the files?

System used:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
Kernel:         4.7.0-040700-generic
```

Comment: possibly a dumb question but what happens if you try the 4.4.0 linux-tools on the newer kernel?

Comment: Does not work sadly :( But yeah was my first thought too!